# what's wrong with my excel value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i got error formatting in excel. in the row "in CCC" value formatting got some error , it
here some screenshot:

[image: error value row]

Answer (score 1):

Two ways, highlight the whole column that you want to change the format.

1. `Right click > Format cells`, and pick the format that you think is applicable under `Number tab.
2. Over the `Ribbon`, you should see a drop down under `Home > Number` and you can pick the format you want there too.  Here is a screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole of the CCC column.

Go to Number format and make sure the same format is entered for the whole column.